# Como corrigir erro em upload de arquivo?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, file-upload, helper

Tenho o seguinte form:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("importCSV", "Administrador", FormMethod.Post, new { @id = "upldFrm", @enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
        {
            <input id="file" name="file" type="file" />
            <label style="color:red; white-space: pre-line">@ViewBag.Message</label>
        }

<script>
        $(function () {
            $("#file").change(function () {
                $("#upldFrm").submit();
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Quando envio qualquer arquivo (`.csv`, `.jpg`, `.txt`, e outros) ele funciona perfeitamente, mas quando tento enviar um arquivo como: `Arquivo 16.03.15.rar` ele nem chega na action, gera o erro da imagem abaixo.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O objetivo é permitir apenas o upload de arquivos `.csv`, mas não posso deixar acontecer problemas como este. Alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: Quando você diz "nem chega na Action", o que exatamente ocorre?

Comment: Atualizei a pergunta meu amigo... Bem, coloquei um breakpoint na action que ele está chamando, e quando envio um arquivo .csv por exemplo, ele chega até lá, mas quando envio o tal arquivo citado, o erro é gerado sem nem mesmo chegar na action.

Comment: Aparentemente o erro é quando envia um arquivo muito grande, independente da extensão

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você tem que aumentar o tamanho máximo da requisição, através da propriedade `maxAllowedContentLength`. Provavelmente o seu .rar está excedendo o tamanho padrão que é de *30.000.000* bytes (aprox. 30MB):

```
<system.web>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="2147483647" />
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
    ...
</system.web>
```

---

```
2147483647 bytes = 2GB
```

Acredito que esse seja um valor absurdo, sugiro configurar conforme suas necessidades. Na verdade, acho que o valor padrão é adequado para o que você está tentando fazer. Tente validar o tamanho do arquivo antes de enviar para o servidor para não ocorrer tal erro.

Pode fazer essa validação com jQuery da seguinte forma:

```
$('#meu-input-upload').bind('change', function() {  
    var tamanho_maximo = 29999999;
    if(this.files[0].size > 29999999) {
        alert("Tamanho máximo excedido");
        this.value = "";
    }
});
```

No caso se o tamanho for maior que `29.999.999` bytes impede o prosseguimento (no lugar do alert faça o tratamento adequado).

Comment: Só para conhecimento o valor de `2147483647` equivale a 2GB.

Answer (score 0):

Você tem que usar uma verificação de extensão dos arquivos que serão enviados, no caso somente arquivos que tenham a extensão **.csv**.

**Exemplo:**

```js
function comprova_extensao(formulario, arquivo) {
  extensoes_permitidas = new Array(".csv");
  meuerro = "";
  if (!arquivo) {
    //Se não tenho arquivo, é porque não se selecionou um arquivo no formulário.
    meuerro = "Não foi selecionado nenhum arquivo";
  } else {
    //recupero a extensão deste nome de arquivo
    extensao = (arquivo.substring(arquivo.lastIndexOf("."))).toLowerCase();
    //alert (extensao);
    //comprovo se a extensão está entre as permitidas
    permitida = false;
    for (var i = 0; i < extensoes_permitidas.length; i++) {
      if (extensoes_permitidas[i] == extensao) {
        permitida = true;
        break;
      }
    }
    if (!permitida) {
      meuerro = "Comprova a extensão dos arquivos a subir. \nSó se podem subir arquivos com extensões: " + extensoes_permitidas.join();
    } else {
      //submeto!
      alert("Tudo correto. Vou submeter o formulário.");
      formulario.submit();
      return 1;
    }
  }
  //se estou aqui é porque não se pode submeter
  alert(meuerro);
  return 0;
}
```

```html
<form method=post action="#" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type=file name="arquivoupload">
  <input type=button name="Submit" value="Enviar" onclick="comprova_extensao(this.form, this.form.arquivoupload.value)">
</form>
```

**Se preferir usar jQuery:**

```js
jQuery.validator.setDefaults({
  debug: true,
  success: "valid"
});
$("#myform").validate({
  rules: {
    field: {
      required: true,
      extension: "csv"
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="http://jqueryvalidation.org/files/dist/additional-methods.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://jqueryvalidation.org/files/dist/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<form id="myform">
  <label for="field">Apenas arquivos no formato .csv</label>
  <input type="file" class="left" id="field" name="field">
  <br/>
  <input type="submit" value="Validate!">
</form>
```

Comment: Apesar de tratar a extensão, o usuário pode simplesmente mudar o nome da extensão e enviar o conteúdo errado de qualquer forma.

Comment: Exemplo troca `.rar` pra `.csv` e enviar.

Answer (score 0):

O erro ocorre porque seu arquivo está com mais de 4 megabytes ([é a configuração padrão do IIS](http://ajaxuploader.com/large-file-upload-iis-asp-net.htm)). Configure seu arquivo `Web.config` com o seguinte:

```
<configuration>
  ...
  <system.web>
    ...
    <!-- Aqui configuro apenas o tamanho da requisição como um todo, e não exatamente o tamanho do anexo -->
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="1048576" />
    ...
  </system.web>
  ...
 <!-- Para o IIS 7 ou superior, também é preciso especificamente configurar o tamanho máximo do arquivo -->
 <system.webServer>
   ...
   <security>
      <requestFiltering>
         <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="1073741824" />
      </requestFiltering>
   </security>
   ...
 </system.webServer>
 ...
</configuration>
```

Importante dizer que `maxRequestLength` está em KBytes, e `maxAllowedContentLength` em bytes. Ambos equivalem a 1 Gb.